# TeX Giving a Blank Console

Tags: pdf, compiling, mac, texshop, paths

Using a Mac on Monterey 12.2.1, and TeXShop on 4.70. When attempting to Typeset, the console window is completely blank. [image: Blank Console]
A "which pdflatex" search in the Terminal gives /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex, but in the Finder, I cannot find that file anywhere, and pdflatex is actually stored in Library/TeXShop/bin/pdflatex. When changing the engine to that path however, I receive a notification from TeXShop saying that path is not found. [image: Error Notification]
Was just wondering a way of how I could get the pdf to compile. My professor is able to compile the code, so it is not a code issue, it is on my end. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you installed MacTeX as the message suggests? https://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: I've installed MacTex, and when I run a "where pdflatex" on the Terminal, it says that it is located in /Library/TeX/bin, but that folder does not exist on the Finder

Comment: Finder doesn't like to let you out of your home directory.  But you can click "Go", and then go to "Computer" (or type cmd-shift-c).  Then you should be able to go to "Macintosh HD" and then see "/Library".  It may also be easier from the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Have you resolved your problem? MacTeX installs its binaries in `/Library/TeX/texbin` and this should be reflected in the settings under Preferences -> Engine.